# How to use a Javascript variable in a PHP block of code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to append some digits to the class names of the elements I am trying to dynamically add on a page. The digit that I will append is by getting the number of the existing target element on the page and I am getting it through the jquery function length.

Here is my code:

```
$("#add_ingr").click(function(){

                var id = $('.save').length + 1;

                var row = '<tr>'
                            +'<td>' 
                                +'<?php $data = array('name' => 'ingr_name[]', 'class' => 'ingr_name'); echo form_input($data); ?>'
                            +'</td>'
                            +'<td>'  
                                +'<?php $data = array('name' => 'ingr_amount[]', 'class' => 'amt'); echo form_input($data); ?>'
                            +'</td>'
                            +'<td>'
                                +'<?php $data = array('name' => 'ingr_unit[]', 'class' => 'unit'); echo form_input($data); ?>'
                                +'<span class="remove">X</span>'
                                +'<span class="save" id="' +count +'">Save</span>' 
                            +'</td>';                                                               
                         +'</tr>';

                $("#ingr_table > tbody").append(row);

            });
```

I'm having troubles because the var id is of javascript and I wanted to append it in a php array value but I am not successfully running the code because it generates errors when I do something like this:

```
$("#add_ingr").click(function(){

                var id = $('.save').length + 1;

                var row = '<tr>'
                            +'<td>' 
                                +'<?php $data = array('name' => 'ingr_name[]', 'class' => 'ingr_name_' +id); echo form_input($data); ?>'
                            +'</td>'
                            +'<td>'  
                                +'<?php $data = array('name' => 'ingr_amount[]', 'class' => 'amt_') +id; echo form_input($data); ?>'
                            +'</td>'
                            +'<td>'
                                +'<?php $data = array('name' => 'ingr_unit[]', 'class' => 'unit_' +id); echo form_input($data); ?>'
                                +'<span class="remove">X</span>'
                                +'<span class="save" id="' +count +'">Save</span>' 
                            +'</td>';                                                               
                         +'</tr>';

                $("#ingr_table > tbody").append(row);

            });
```

Does anybody have a solution for my problem? Thank you very much for those who would help.

Comment: What is the problem? What errors do you get?

Comment: I am getting this: unterminated string literal error.

Comment: Do you realise that all of your PHP code runs on the web server, and all of your JavaScript runs on in the web browser, and so your PHP can't access any JavaScript variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need CodeIgniter's `form_input` helper?

```
function form_input($data = '', $value = '', $extra = '')
{
  $defaults = array('type' => 'text', 'name' => (( ! is_array($data)) ? $data : ''), 'value' => $value);

  return "<input "._parse_form_attributes($data, $defaults).$extra." />";
}
```

As this will just return `<input name=$name class=$class/>`, 
I guess you can convert it to this.

```
var row = '<tr>'
            +'<td>' 
                +'<input name="ingr_name[]" class="ingr_name_'+id+'"/>'
            +'</td>'
            +'<td>'
                +'<input name="ingr_amount[]" class="amt_'+id+'"/>'
            +'</td>'
            +'<td>'
                +'<input name="ingr_unit[]" class="unit_'+id+'"/>'
                +'<span class="remove">X</span>'
                +'<span class="save" id="' +count +'">Save</span>' 
            +'</td>';                                                               
         +'</tr>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Ace. I have followed your suggestion and I achieve my target concatenating the id on the class name. I thought I am compelled to use the CI's form_helper because I am using the framework.

Comment: Ah, yes. It's ideal to use helpers. But if it does not fit your needs, you can skip them and go for a simpler solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

The unterminated string literal error is probably because of the `;` after

```
+'</td>';
```

The code is pretty difficult to read because you're mixing PHP and JavaScript. I would recommend moving all the PHP into one block, and then outputting only the PHP variables: `<?php echo $data; ?>` for clarity.

Comment: I already removed the ; after the +</td> but still the unterminated string literal error persists. That's what I am having a hard time with because I would assign the digits according to the number of elements present in the page and I am doing the count using jquery since I don't know of a way to count the number of elements of a specific selector.